# Microsoft Exchange Online Plan one Licence fee for additional user

Tags: microsoft-office-365, licensing, exchangeonline

I want to know how Microsoft will charge license fee for new license added to the same subscription, I contacted MS but didn't get much clarity from the guy or i was not able to understand what me is trying to say.

I have directly purchase Exchange Online Plan 1 few years back and since then i keep adding or removing license based on the requirement i have.

So for example let us us say i purchased "Exchange Online Plan" 1st June 2017 for 20 users on 1st December 2017 i purchase another 5 licenses for same plan which adds up my total licenses to 25 as of date.

Now my question is for 20 user license which i purchase on 1st June 2017 i will be paying for 12 on next renewal date 1st June 2018 which is quite clear.

but how will Microsoft charge me for the addition 5 user license which i purchase on 1st December 2017, will Microsoft charge these 5 license for 6 months or they will charge me for 12 months on the due billing date which is 1st June 2018.

Reply from MS `This is just a friendly follow up in your case. Thank you for your email. When you purchase actual user product licenses that will be the start date and start to count the 12 month period.`

I am not able to understand from this reply can anyone help clarify.

My understanding is that for other 5 user which i purchased in December i will be charged only for 6months on the next billing dates

20 User  charged at 12 months at $4 per month on next billing date 1st June 2018

5User  charged at 6 months at $4 per month on next billing date 1st June 2018

Answer (score 0):

Do you pay those new licenses by month or year?
[image]

The new 5 license begins charging when it purchases, i.e. 1st December 2017 to 30th November 2018 if pay it by year.

You can open Office 365 portal, Billing---> Descriptions to check.

Comment: I have  `Exchange Online (Plan 1) $48.00 user/year ` since 1st June 2015 and it doesnt show me option which you are i think it is /year for me as i get billed years but if i purchase addition license then i get some extra bills  for that year but amount which is billed is confusing..